# Can I combined these two updates?

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgresql, I want to UPDATE two columns from two different tables that share the same name. I can do it with two separate queries..

```
UPDATE ingredients i
SET units = 'kg'
FROM products p
WHERE i.product_id = p.id and p.units = 'l';

UPDATE products p
SET units = 'kg'
WHERE p.units = 'l';
```

.. as long as I update the ingredients first as I'm filtering on that column in the products table.

But i'm curious to know if its possible to combine these and do it in one query?

Essentially what I want is:

```
UPDATE products p, ingredients i
SET p.units = 'kg', i.units = 'kg'
WHERE p.id = i.product_id AND p.units = 'l';
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to do it that way, the former works, I just wanted to know if there's a better way?

Comment: No, not possible. You could wrap both updates in a CTE to make it a single query. You could also use two update statements, wrapped into a single transaction.